# Plone - embed the content of an internal link in a page

Tags: plone

I have a list of pages that have to appear in different places of my Plone. If I use an internal link, I see an HTML link in the page but instead of that I would like to see the embedded content of the linked page.

I've tried to install some link plugins (Smart Link, vs.alias...) but I'm not able to find the solution.

I'm using Plone 4.3.

Comment: Could any of the answers help you further?

Comment: I'm working on that but at the end, I've decided to use collections joining the pages using a criteria (in my case a tag name). I've found two problems with this approach: 1) the searches don't work in the collections and 2) it is necessary to simulate the order of the pages that compose the collection using an attribute. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand 1) you mean you don't get search results listed in the collection after setting criteria? About 2): Collection have some options for ordering (by date, aphabetically by title, etc), maybe you find a fit.

Comment: 1) The search control filters by the name of the collections/pages and by the content of the pages. It doesn't filter by the content of the collection (It make sense because the collection content is dynamically generated). 2) Exactly. I've added a number as a prefix to the name of the pages to ensure the order.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any Plone Plugin, which satisfy your requirement.

A long time ago i wrote this small js to show internal links in a popup using Plone's `prepOverlay`.

In this case you can put a `popup` custom CSS class on the internal link with TinyMCE.

It simply shows the content area of the given URL.

```
$(function(){
    jq('a.popup').prepOverlay({
        subtype:'ajax',
        urlmatch:'$',urlreplace:' #content > *'
    });
});
```

I guess this is a good starting point for your own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could think of a criterion like location, contenttype, etc., to distinct, which articles should be picked (in worst case use collective.flag), then fetch them with a collection, to give you the links as a resultlist, and set its view to `all_content`, a nice feature, introduced in the Plone-4 series.